# How to move error message to rabbitmq dead letter queue

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I read a lot of documentation/stackoverflow and still I have problem when exception occurs to move message to dead letter queue. I'm using spring-boot Here is my configuration:

```
@Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Bean
    RetryOperationsInterceptor interceptor() {
        RepublishMessageRecoverer recoverer = new RepublishMessageRecoverer(rabbitTemplate, "error_exchange ", "error_key");
        return RetryInterceptorBuilder
            .stateless()
            .recoverer(recoverer)
            .build();
    }
```

Dead letter queue:

```
Features    
x-dead-letter-routing-key:  error_key
x-dead-letter-exchange: error_exchange
durable:    true
Policy  DLX
```

Name of the queue: error

My exchange:
name:error_exchange 
binding: to: error, routing_key: error_key

Here is my conusmer:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${rss_reader_chat_queue}")
    public void consumeMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            List<ChatMessage> chatMessages = messageTransformer.transformMessage(message);
            List<ChatMessage> save = chatMessageRepository.save(chatMessages);
            sendMessagesToChat(save);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException(ex);
        }
    }
```

So when I send an invalid message and some exception occurs, it happens once (and it's good because previously message was sent over and over again) but the message doesn't go to my dead letter queue. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to show the rest of your configuration - boot properties, queue `@Bean`s etc. You also seem to have some confusion between using a republishing recoverer Vs dead letter queues; they are different ways to achieve similar results. You typically wouldn't use both.

Here's a simple boot app that demonstrates using a DLX/DLQ...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So43694619Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So43694619Application.class, args);
        context.close();
    }

    @Autowired
    RabbitTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    AmqpAdmin admin;

    private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {
        this.template.convertAndSend("so43694619main", "foo");
        this.latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        this.admin.deleteExchange("so43694619dlx");
        this.admin.deleteQueue("so43694619main");
        this.admin.deleteQueue("so43694619dlx");
    }


    @Bean
    public Queue main() {
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
        args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "so43694619dlx");
        args.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "so43694619dlxRK");
        return new Queue("so43694619main", true, false, false, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue dlq() {
        return new Queue("so43694619dlq");
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange dlx() {
        return new DirectExchange("so43694619dlx");
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding dlqBinding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(dlq()).to(dlx()).with("so43694619dlxRK");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so43694619main")
    public void listenMain(String in) {
        throw new AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException("failed");
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so43694619dlq")
    public void listenDlq(String in) {
        System.out.println("ReceivedFromDLQ: " + in);
        this.latch.countDown();
    }

}
```

Result:

```
ReceivedFromDLQ: foo
```

Comment: Yes, just a moment ago I noticed my error. Thanks for the explanation. Queues which get error message did not have set dlx policy. Now when I set it, the RetryOperationsInterceptor is not need anymore.